# Задача на отрезки на числовой прямой

Tags: java, алгоритм

Записался на курс алгоритмы и структуры данных. Не могу никак решить задачу: На числовой прямой окрасили N отрезков. Известны координаты левого и правого концов каждого отрезка (Li и Ri). Найти сумму длин частей числовой прямой, окрашенных ровно в один слой. Используемый язык java, другие также принимаются

**input**

```
     3

    1 4
    7 8
    2 5
```

**output** 3
**input**

```
     9

    2 9
    0 1 
    7 12 
    5 12 
    9 13 
    9 14 
    10 18
    17 18
    2  10
```

**output** 
4

**UPD**
Что я пытался  делать
1) сортировать все точки и держать к какому концу отрезка она находиться 
на 1 первый тест легко пишутся условия когда нужно посчитать сумму ко 2му не подходит

```
 int sum = 0;
        if(mass.length==1) sum+=mass[1].dot-mass[0].dot;
        else { sum+= mass[1].dot-mass[0].dot;
            for (int i = 2; i < n * 2; i++) {
                if(mass[i].l==false){ // если это не левый конец
                    if (mass[i-1].l==false) sum+=mass[i].dot-mass[i-1].dot;
                    if(mass[i-1].l==true&&mass[i-2].l==false) sum+=mass[i].dot-mass[i-1].dot;
                }else {

                    if(mass[i-1].l==true) sum+= mass[i].dot-mass[i-1].dot;

                }
```

2) Сортировать все отрезки в виде классов (point( 1 4) point (2 5) point (7 8))
также с ифами все возможные варианты не получилось покрыть,
Есть какие-то еще идеи или только в этих 2-х направлениях нужно искать подходящие условия срабатывания счетчика

**UPD**

Вот похожая задача   на  нахождение длины объединения отрезков на прямой.
ток не совсем понимаю синтаксис и как перевести на java

```
unsigned segments_union_measure (const vector <pair <int,int> > & a)
{
    unsigned n = a.size();
    vector <pair <int,bool> > x (n*2);
    for (unsigned i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i*2] = make_pair (a[i].first, false);
        x[i*2+1] = make_pair (a[i].second, true);
    }

    sort (x.begin(), x.end());

    unsigned result = 0;
    unsigned c = 0;
    for (unsigned i=0; i<n*2; i++)
    {
        if (c && i)
            result += unsigned (x[i].first - x[i-1].first);
        if (x[i].second)
            ++c;
        else
            --c;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: за вас тут не кто программу не будет писать. покажите свои труды, может поможем с проблемами

Comment: Сорри, подправил 2 пример

Comment: Спасибо сделал!!

Comment: Правильный ответ 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задачи на интервалы решаются сортировкой координат, и перебором подряд от меньших к большим, считая «текущее» кол-во активных.

Напр., даны отрезки [1,5], [2,3], [3,9]

Тут ещё важно, каковы крайние точки - для простоты считаем, что все края «включены».

Сортируем координаты, не забывая, где какая - одни из них точки входа (in), другие - выхода (out):

```
1 i
2 i
3 o
3 i
5 o
9 o
```

Изначально кол-во включённых слоёв `0`. Когда "i" добавляем 1, когда "o" – вычитаем. Пошли:

```
- -  0
1 i  1 - начался нужный отрезок - в результат добавим [1, ?
2 i  2 - != 1, закончился – в результат добавили [1,2]
3 o  1 - снова начался нужный
3 i  2 - и тут же закончился, ничего не делаем
5 o  1 - начался нужный [5, ?
9 o  0 - закончился, в результат добавили [5,9]
```

Результат: [1,2], [5,9]. Складываем длины 1+4 = 5. Ответ: 5

Comment: Структура массива посложнее, но должно работать.

Comment: «Структура массива посложнее» – что?

Comment: Да, также решил на java, как и  указали в комментариях к моему посту. Мне кажется это самый простой способ

Comment: @ketchyn Главное, что были идеи и появился выбор.

Comment: Можно сразу писать +-1. И лучше отдельным массивом, что упрощает сортировку и доступ.

Answer (score 1):

В условии задачи было сказано: "ровно в один слой", и идеи с объединением отрезков здесь не проходят.
Но можно воспользоваться методом интервалов, для чего:
1. Свалить все начала и концы отрезков в один массив и упорядочить.
2. На каждом из полученных отрезков ненулевой длины выбрать внутреннюю точку (например, середину) и подсчитать, скольким исходным отрезкам она принадлежит.
3 Просуммировать длины отрезков, для которых сумма по п.3 равна 1.

Программа на PHP:

```
$segments = [
    [2,9],
    [0,1],
    [7,12],
    [5,12],
    [9,13],
    [9,14],
    [10,18],
    [17,18],
    [2,10]
];

var_dump($segments);
$begend=[];
foreach ($segments as $seg) array_push($begend, $seg[0], $seg[1]);
sort($begend);
var_dump($begend);
$cnt = count($begend);
$begin = $begend[0];
$length = 0;
for($i=1; $i < $cnt; $i++){ // проверяем каждый интервал, образованный краями отрезков
    $end = $begend[$i];
    if($end!=$begin){
        $c = 0;
        $aver = ($begin+$end)/2;
        foreach($segments as $seg){
            if ($seg[0]<$aver && $aver < $seg[1]) $c++;
        }
        if($c==1) $length += ($end - $begin);
        print("<br>начало: $begin конец: $end повторов: $c  сумма = $length");
        $begin = $end;
    }           
} 
print("<br>length = $length");
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 9
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 7
      1 => int 12
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 12
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 13
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 14
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 18
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 17
      1 => int 18
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 10
array (size=18)
  0 => int 0
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 5
  5 => int 7
  6 => int 9
  7 => int 9
  8 => int 9
  9 => int 10
  10 => int 10
  11 => int 12
  12 => int 12
  13 => int 13
  14 => int 14
  15 => int 17
  16 => int 18
  17 => int 18

начало: 0 конец: 1 повторов: 1 сумма = 1
начало: 1 конец: 2 повторов: 0 сумма = 1
начало: 2 конец: 5 повторов: 2 сумма = 1
начало: 5 конец: 7 повторов: 3 сумма = 1
начало: 7 конец: 9 повторов: 4 сумма = 1
начало: 9 конец: 10 повторов: 5 сумма = 1
начало: 10 конец: 12 повторов: 5 сумма = 1
начало: 12 конец: 13 повторов: 3 сумма = 1
начало: 13 конец: 14 повторов: 2 сумма = 1
начало: 14 конец: 17 повторов: 1 сумма = 4
начало: 17 конец: 18 повторов: 2 сумма = 4
length = 4
```

Comment: причём тут «середина» отрезка?

Comment: @Sergiks Подходит любая внутренняя точка отрезка p*$end + (1-p)*$begin при 0<p<1.

Comment: $Sergiks спасибо за вопрос, я уточнил описание

Comment: Лишняя сложность: в цикле по каждой точке, вложенный цикл по всем сегментам.

Comment: @Sergiks Учёл замечание при доработке версии.

Answer (score 1):

Шлифуем алгоритм (с учётом замечания [Sergics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7161/sergiks)):

1. Создаём массив начал и концов по отрезкам.
2. Создаём массив знаков: +1 для начала отрезка и -1 - для конца.
3. Сортируем оба массива по координате (процедура array_multisort()).
4. Количество слоёв получаем суммированием массива знаков.

Программа (PHP):

```
$segments = [
    [2,9],
    [0,1],
    [7,12],
    [5,12],
    [9,13],
    [9,14],
    [10,18],
    [17,18],
    [2,10]
];

var_dump($segments);
$begend=[];
$sign = [];
foreach ($segments as $seg){
    array_push($begend, $seg[0], $seg[1]);
    array_push($sign, 1, -1);
} 
array_multisort($begend, $sign);
$size = count($begend);
$length = 0;
$c = $sign[0];
$begin = $begend[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++){
    if($c == 1) $length += $begend[$i] - $begin;
    printf("<br>Интервал: [%2d,%2d]&ensp; Знак: %s&ensp;  Слоёв: $c&ensp; Сумма: $length", 
        $begin, $begend[$i], ($sign[$i-1]>0)?"+":"-");
    $c += $sign[$i];
    $begin = $begend[$i];
}
print("<br><br>length = $length");
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 9
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 7
      1 => int 12
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 5
      1 => int 12
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 13
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 14
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 18
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 17
      1 => int 18
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 2
      1 => int 10

Интервал: [ 0, 1]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 1  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 1, 2]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 0  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 2, 2]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 1  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 2, 5]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 2  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 5, 7]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 3  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 7, 9]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 4  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 9, 9]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 5  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 9, 9]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 6  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [ 9,10]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 5  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [10,10]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 4  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [10,12]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 5  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [12,12]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 4  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [12,13]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 3  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [13,14]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 2  Сумма: 1
Интервал: [14,17]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 1  Сумма: 4
Интервал: [17,18]  Знак: +  Слоёв: 2  Сумма: 4
Интервал: [18,18]  Знак: -  Слоёв: 1  Сумма: 4

length = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется самым простым решением, создать массив длиной N, где N - длина числовой прямой. Массив заполнен нулями. Далее нанести отрезки на массив, увеличивая на 1 каждый фрагмент(отрезок) массива. Последним этапом пройти по массиву и подсчитать количество 1.

Для первого примера:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0] // размерность - 7
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0] // [1,4]
[1,1,1,0,0,0,1] // [7,8]
[1,2,2,1,0,0,1] // [2,5]
```

Comment: А если край отрезка 0.5 или 999999?

Comment: предполагаю, задача на целочисленные координаты.

Comment: 999999 - тоже целочисленная координата. И что теперь, массив на 1000000 точек заводить?

Comment: также интересное решение, только ресурсоёмкое, получается нам надо для каждой точки заново проходить массив

Answer (score 0):

Вот программа на java кот может решить вашу задачу

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Point[] points = new Point[nextInt()<<1];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            points[i] = new Point(nextInt(), 1);
            points[++i] = new Point(nextInt(), -1);
        }
        mergeSortIterative(points, 0, points.length, (p1, p2) -> {
            int val = p1.getP() - p2.getP();
            return val == 0 ? -p1.getV() : val;
        });
        int res = countLen( points );
        System.out.println(res);
    }

     public static int countLen( Point[] arr ){
        int  res = 0;
        int count = arr[0].getV();
        Point prev = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            count += arr[i].getV();
            arr[i].setV(count);
            if ( prev.getV() == 1 && prev.getP() != arr[i].getP() )
                res += arr[i].getP() - prev.getP();
            prev = arr[i];
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static <T extends Object> void mergeSortIterative(T[] arr, int l, int r, Comparator<T> comp) {
        if (l + 1 < r) {
            int m = ( l + r ) >>> 1;
            mergeSortIterative(arr, l, m, comp);
            mergeSortIterative(arr, m, r, comp);

            int len = r - l;
            T[] tmp = (T[]) new Object[len];
            for (int i = 0, j1 = l, j2 = m ; i < len; i++) {
                if ( j2 >= r || j1 < m && comp.compare(arr[j1], arr[j2]) < 0 )
                    tmp[i] = arr[j1++];
                else
                    tmp[i] = arr[j2++];
            }
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0 , arr, l, len);
        }
    }

    private static int nextInt() throws IOException {
        int d;
        int val = 0;
        while ((d = System.in.read()) == 32) ;
        if (d < 0) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        boolean flag = false;
        if (d == '-') {
            flag = true;
            d = System.in.read();
        }
        do {
            val += d - 48;
            if ((d = System.in.read()) < 48 || d > 57) break;
            val *= 10;
        } while (true);
        return flag ? -val : val;
    }

    private static class Point{
        private int p;
        private int v;
        public Point(int p, int v){
            this.p = p;
            this.v = v;
        }
        public int getP() {
            return p;
        }
        public int getV() {
            return v;
        }
        public void setV(int v) {
            this.v = v;
        }
        public void setP(int p) {

            this.p = p;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getP()+"("+getV()+") ";
        }
    }
}
```